# Is it possible to decode a QR Code from photo library of a device in iOS?

Tags: ios, qr-code, barcode-scanner, zbar-sdk, zbar

I'm using Zbarqrcode reader iOS SDK. I want to scan a photo which has Qrcode in it from photo library of a device( not simulator ). Is it possible to do this? if yes, How?